# How to fix regional settings for jQuery datepicker so it works in Firefox and IE7?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, validation, datetime, datepicker

I am using jQuery' s datepicker and asp.net MVC4. The datepicker works in Firefox but in IE7 i get the message through the asp.net's validation that the field is not a date.

This is the code for the datepicker

```
if (!Modernizr.inputtypes.date) {
        $(function() {
            $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['en-GB']);
            $(".datefield").datepicker();
        });
    }
```

This is my globalization setting in Web.config

`<globalization uiCulture="en-GB" culture="en-GB" />`

E.g. in Firefox the date is shown as "19/03/2012" string and accepted by the asp.net's validation setup (client and server side). In IE7 the same date string is not accepted on the client. If i change it to "03/19/2012" the client accepts the date but then the server throws an exception - "InvalidOperationException. Nullable object must have a value."

My viewModel uses a null-able DateTime that i cast to a non null-able DateTime in the controllers post action. This works in Firefox but in IE7 the value for the date from the viewModel is null. What is the problem?

Comment: Darin Dimitrov has the right answer but also look at my tutorial http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/using-the-html5-and-jquery-ui-datepicker-popup-calendar-with-aspnet-mvc/using-the-html5-and-jquery-ui-datepicker-popup-calendar-with-aspnet-mvc-part-1

Comment: Thank you, I have already used your fine tutorial to come this far with the datepicker. But it doesn't deal with globalization issues.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following line does nothing:

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['en-GB']);
```

if you don't include the [corresponding language file](http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ui/i18n/) which is not included by default in the ASP.NET MVC 4 template.

You may try setting the format explicitly:

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
```

But this only concerns how the date should be formatted after selecting it in the datepicker. It has nothing to do with validation.

The client side validation is performed by the `jquery.validate` plugin which in turn uses either the browser currently configured culture (which might explain the discrepancies you are observing between FF and IE, for example one might be configured to use en-GB and the other en-US) or ISO dates.

You could override this custom validation and make it use your custom format to ensure that this will work cross browser:

```
if (!Modernizr.inputtypes.date) {
    $(function () {
        $.datepicker.setDefaults({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
        $('.datefield').datepicker();
    });

    jQuery.validator.addMethod(
        'date',
        function (value, element, params) {
            if (this.optional(element)) {
                return true;
            };
            var result = false;
            try {
                $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', value);
                result = true;
            } catch (err) {
                result = false;
            }
            return result;
        },
        ''
    );
}
```

Comment: How do i include the correct datepicker language file in the code? The language files are already in a subdirectory (i18n) of my Scripts directory.

Comment: @mrt181, ah sorry, I thought you don't have those files. You include them the same way you would include any javascript file: using the `script` tag.

Comment: I have this in my code
`<script src="@System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/Scripts/js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/Scripts/i18n/js")" type="text/javascript"></script></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: @mrt181, wow, that would explain your datetime formatting problems. Maybe you have some other part of the code where you have included a wrong i18n file or set the wrong language.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a datepicker problem but a validation problem. The validation shows browser specific behavior.

Comment: @mrt181, actually it is not browser specific, but culture specific. Did you try defining a custom adapter as shown in my answer?

Comment: Yes, just used the custom validator which worked. Would be helpful to know why Firefox seems to adhere to the culture settings while IE7 does not.

Comment: I forgot to mention that firefox and ie7 are both german and both run on a german version of windows xp

Comment: Your *corresponding language file* `i18n` link is now broken.

Answer (score 3):

Jquery localization files are available at :

http://nuget.org/packages/jQuery.UI.i18n

simply run :

**Install-Package jQuery.UI.i18n** and add a script reference to "Scripts/jquery-ui-i18n.js"

from package manager console, then this will work:
**$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['en-GB']);**