# why does a nullable datetime trying to validate the date, when it is empty?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am building an MVC 4 application.  I have the following property

```
 [Display(Name = "ExpiryDateLabel", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Manage.PrereqDetail))]
  public DateTime? ExpiryDate { get; set; }
```

in my View when i post it back with an empty value it says

The field Expiry Date: must be a date

why is that happening?

Comment: i am not really sure what you are saying... The ExpiryDate is a nullable DateTime

Comment: Assign the value DateTime.MinValue to it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are doing localization on ExpiryDate property and if you are using jQuery validation, you might wanna check following post explaining the solution to same problem.

[How to fix regional settings for jQuery datepicker so it works in Firefox and IE7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9773746/how-to-fix-regional-settings-for-jquery-datepicker-so-it-works-in-firefox-and-ie)