# Date validation not working in chrome after publishing on Azure

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, azure

I had [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15706455/the-field-date-must-be-a-date-in-mvc-in-chrome) problem. One of the answers helped me fix my problem but, after publishing the website on Azure, the problem persists. I've checked the jquery.validate file that was published via Visual Studio Online and it has my fix.
Any ideas, what I'm facing here?

Comment: Are you saying it works in localhost but fails on Azure?

Comment: Exactly. I know it makes very little sense, but that's what's happening. I republished it right after running it on loclhost and got the same problem.

Comment: I'll try to do the validation via jquery on the cshtml file, not on the jquery-validate (changing the original code, that is). I'll post any results.

Comment: You link has the date format dd/mm/yyyy and I'm assuming you are using the same format. Have you set globalisation to the required culture in your web.config file?

Comment: I didn't! I didn't even know that was necessary. Trying it right now, but you can give an answer on how to properly set it. I'm from Brazil, if you want to give the code with my localization, I'd be glad.

Comment: Just tried using "pt-BR" both on culture and uiculture attributes. No success.

Comment: In your web config file in the `<system.web>` section add the following `<globalization culture="pt-BR" uiCulture="pt-BR"/>`. If this works, I'll post answer with more detail

Comment: It didn't work. Still showing the same problem. I really thought it could be this.

Comment: One final thought. Have you included jquery globalisation? Alternatively, have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9773746/how-to-fix-regional-settings-for-jquery-datepicker-so-it-works-in-firefox-and-ie)

Comment: I'm not sure what jQuery globalization is. And that answer doesn't really work for me.

Comment: [jquery globalize](https://www.nuget.org/packages/jquery-globalize/) is a NuGet package designed to work with jqueryUI

Comment: I've installed the package but I'm not sure on how to use it