# Servicestack request datetime deserialization - how to make it ignore current culture?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, servicestack, deserialization

Servicestack request datetime deserialization works fine on my local machine with Danish language/region - but on the production server it does not work because it has english culture.

**How to make it ignore current culture?**

This works local:
ourdomain.dk/api/json/reply/LoadGuardBookView?date=24/07/2014

This works on production:
ourdomain.dk/api/json/reply/LoadGuardBookView?date=07/24/2014

Different culture dateformats. How to make it work on both with the same code?
The call is from javascript so I doesn't have culture right at hand.

**Edit 1:**

```
var date = $.datepicker.formatDate("d/m/yy", $("#calendar").datepicker("getDate"));
$.get("/api/json/reply/LoadGuardBookView", {
    Date: date
}, function (data) {
    ...
}).fail(function (e) {
   ...
    console.log("Error reloading GuardBook");
});
```

Server:

```
public class GuardBookService : Service, IGet<LoadGuardBookView>
{
    public object Get(LoadGuardBookView request)
    {
        ...
    }

    public class LoadGuardBookView
    {
        public DateTime Date { get; set; } 
    }
}
```

Exception:

> {"ResponseStatus":{"ErrorCode":"SerializationException","Message":"Could
>   not deserialize '*.LoadGuardBookView' request using
>   KeyValueDataContractDeserializer: 'date=24-07-2014'.\nError:
>   'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException:
>   KeyValueDataContractDeserializer: Error converting to type: String was
>   not recognized as a valid DateTime. ---> System.FormatException:
>   String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.\r\n   at
>   System.DateTime.Parse(String s, IFormatProvider provider,
>   DateTimeStyles styles)\r\n   at
>   ServiceStack.Text.Common.DateTimeSerializer.ParseShortestXsdDateTime(String
>   dateTimeStr)\r\n   at
>   ServiceStack.Text.Common.DeserializeBuiltin`1.<GetParseFn>b__b(String
>   value)\r\n   at
>   ServiceStack.ServiceModel.Serialization.StringMapTypeDeserializer.PopulateFromMap(Object
>   instance, IDictionary`2 keyValuePairs, List`1
>   ignoredWarningsOnPropertyNames)\r\n   --- End of inner exception stack
>   trace ---\r\n   at
>   ServiceStack.ServiceModel.Serialization.StringMapTypeDeserializer.PopulateFromMap(Object
>   instance, IDictionary`2 keyValuePairs, List`1
>   ignoredWarningsOnPropertyNames)\r\n   at
>   ServiceStack.ServiceModel.Serialization.KeyValueDataContractDeserializer.Parse(IDictionary`2
>   keyValuePairs, Type returnType)\r\n   at
>   ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Support.EndpointHandlerBase.DeserializeHttpRequest(Type
>   operationType, IHttpRequest httpReq, String contentType)'"}}

Comment: It would help if we could see your code.

Comment: There is really no code of relavans to show - but I will add some.. See edit

Comment: See code and exception in my edit.

Comment: Have you tried adding this in your web.config? `<system.web><globalization uiCulture="da-DK" culture="da-DK"></globalization></system.web>` Maybe servicestack respect the culture setting. But this problem will reappear again if your browser is sending another culture format. Best bet is to force your jQuery to send in `yyyy-MM-dd` so that the server side knows what to anticipate.

Comment: Refer to this on how to set jQuery datepicker culture. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9773746/how-to-fix-regional-settings-for-jquery-datepicker-so-it-works-in-firefox-and-ie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround that works on both local and production:

> ourdomain.dk/api/json/reply/LoadGuardBookView?date=2014-07-24

**Edit:** As the comments state - this is the way to do it. (YYYY-MM-DD)

Comment: @mythz is correct.  May as well use the ISO standard "YYYY-MM-DD" format.  Anything else, and you're asking for heartburn.